# What is best for saving lot of extra detail of user?

Tags: database, user-meta

In my site i need to store 200 extra data for each user. Now i know about the user meta option. But is it a good way to save 200extra field for each user?

Or should i create an extra table in the database to do the work.

Comment: I would probably create a new table. It also depends on how often you will need to access the data.

Comment: do you need to query users on the data, i.e. get users based on the value of a specific piece of extra data? any data that doesn't need to used in a query can be stored as array within a single field

Comment: I only need to get data of a user. No need to do any query using that data. How an array can be saved in field? Can you give me some example url?

Answer (score 0):

You can store multiple pieces of data within a single field by passing an array rather than a string:

```
$user_data = array(
    'favorite_color' => 'blue',
    'favorite_animal' => 'cat',
    'favorite_city' => 'paris' 
);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_data', $user_data );
```

WordPress will serialize this data for you on save, and unserialize back into an array when it is retrieved:

```
$user_data = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_data', true );
echo $user_data['favorite_color'];
```

The caveat is that it will actually result in a slightly larger amount of data, but it will decrease the number of rows consumed by the data.